# What is the app to use for planning a PhD tasks?

Tags: task-management

I want to consider each chapter in PhD as a project and inside each chapter I want to write tasks for specific days to be completed in. Then after that I can have a Day view to focus only on the tasks that I have to do today and to know which chapter this task is related to. It would also be helpful if the app provide tomorrow view or this week view to show the upcoming tasks.

I need the app to be available to download on Android device, and Windows 10 PC.

Which app to use for this?

Comment: I am a big fan of https://www.abstractspoon.com/ Check it out

Answer (score 0):

I use Asana.  It is available on multiple platforms and seamlessly syncs between them.  The free version is limited to one user, so it will be fine for you.

It has

- Projects
- Tasks
- Sub tasks
- Due Dates
- Done Flag

Etc

Comment: it seems that it is for teams not for individual use!